# How to distribute a PhoneGap compiled IOS app without the Apple's app store

Tags: ios, cordova, mobile

I'm developing an HTML5 mobile app using DevExpress DevExtreme libraries.
Once the app is done, and the native (PhoneGap) package is generated, I need to be able to distribute this app to ONLY a FEW SELECT PEOPLE, thus using Apple app store is not an option.
Is there a way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes there is an option but for that you need apple developer account.
1) Write down UDID of all devices on which you want to install app.
2) Create a certificate including all that UDID's.
3)Generate IPA.
4)Open DIAWI.com ,Upload ipa, a link will be generated.
5)Download the app from that link.

Comment: This sounds like a reasonable procedure. I will sign up for an Apple developer account, and will try to follow these steps

Comment: This process worked on my phone, so I expect that other phones would be similar. Thanks!

Comment: Yes Eugene it will work on other IOS devices also, all you need is there UDID.

Answer (score 4):

You need apple developer account to do this.

1. Create App Id.
2. Write down all your UDIDs for devices and Add it into the account.**Note :**(In case you enrolled in **iOS Developer        Program** you will have up to **100** Device. in the **Enterprise Program** There is no limit to the number of devices you can distribute to
3. Create a distribution provisioning profile that includes all the devices that will have the app.
4. As **Piyush matta** stated use DIAWI.com to generate the download link

**Important Note** : The In-House apps mentioned by wbt11a is existed **ONLY** in **iOS Developer Enterprise Program** (the one with $299/year) not in the normal **iOS Developer Program** ($99/year).

Comment: Thank you for alerting me to the fact that InHouse was only for Enterprise, so I did not have to chase that!

Comment: @EugeneGoldberg You are welcome :),sorry for writing a new reply to add these notes but i still not able to add a comment to others replies by others (below 50 :D)

Answer (score 2):

As Piyush matta has stated, you have to have an Apple Developer Account.

To my knowledge, there are two types of Provisioning Profiles you can choose to distribute outside of the App Store.

1. Ad Hoc - "Create a distribution provisioning profile to install your app on a limited number of registered devices." --this is what Piyush Matta is referring to
2. In House - "Distribute proprietary, in-house iOS apps to your employees. You can also securely host and wirelessly distribute or update in-house apps to employees, keeping them current anywhere, anytime."

The second sounds like what you want.

Comment: Are there specific steps that implement this InHouse option?

Comment: Under Provisioning Profiles in your account on developer.apple.com, go to Distribution | click '+' | click In House

Comment: If you don't have access to an Enterprise license you can still do Ad hoc.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using DevExtreme Mobile (http://js.devexpress.com/MobileDevelopment/) then output it as a web app, upload it to a server, and email people the URL for download.

Comment: Yes, I am using MobileDevelopment. Is there a specific option in VS to package the output as a Web app? What should actually end up being in the output folder?

Comment: I don't use the product myself, so you'll have to ask support that question.